# What is Electromagnetic Cross Section?

Tags: semiconductors, manufacturing

What is Electromagnetic Cross Section?
(shock section)

Hello, I have a question regarding the manufacturing process of electronic components in the case of the silicon deposition and corrosion process. My biggest doubt is the behavior of the plasma interacting in the reactor, I don't know if it's correct I would like someone to help me.

What I understood from the subject:
If you look at the image, it shows a capacitor (in the simplified case, a PECVD or RIE plasma reactor) where the particles descend from the plate and then it will collide with the particles on the bottom plate, in this case it is in the middle where the plasma wants to pass. In practice we have three directions (vectors) x, y and z, the magnetic effect occurs in the plasma where the particles have two directions or two directions in a spiral effect, so the shock is greater in the sample. In its behavior taking advantage where the field can move in the sample without having to move it.

Is correct?

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted to physics here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719135/what-is-electromagnetic-cross-section-shock-section

Comment: @Andyaka - sorry but this is an answer, you ask me a question.

Comment: Apparently, cross-posting is not well-liked in the community LUFER. BTW I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Andyaka-the comment I made that the link you gave me it doesn't answer my question.you gave me the link of another platform where I ask the same question.I just wanted to know what I wrote is correct or is there something else that has to be presented in this information.

Comment: @LUFER could you delete one of the questions? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @VoltageSpike - I can't because I didn't ask this question

Comment: @LUFER - Hi, You replied to *Voltage Spike* "*I didn't ask this question*". What do you mean? A few comments above, you said to *Andy aka* that they had added "*the link of another platform where I ask the same question*". So your reply to *Voltage Spike* is unclear, since you have already said that you asked the question on Physics.SE and we know you asked it here on EE.SE too. So please reply *clearly* to the request from *Voltage Spike* to either do as asked, or explain why you will not do that. Thanks. (IMHO it's better suited to Physics.SE, but some people here are also physicists.)